# Define columns on polymorphic many to many relations with eagerload

Tags: php, laravel

I can't select columns in eager loading using Many To Many Polymorphic relations

My request is :

```
Etape::with(array('entreprises'=> function($query) {
    return $query->select('entreprises.id');
}))->get();
```

The relations are defined as following

```
class Etape extends Eloquent {
    public function entreprises()
        {
            return $this->morphedByMany('Entreprise', 'etapeable')->withPivot('date');
        }
}

class Entreprise extends Eloquent {
    public function etapes() {
        return $this->morphToMany('Etape', 'etapeable')->withPivot('date')->orderBy('date');
    }
}
```

These SQL requests are executed :

```
SELECT * FROM `etapes` WHERE `etapes`.`deleted_at` IS NULL

SELECT `entreprises`.`id`, `entreprises`.*, `etapeables`.`etape_id` as `pivot_etape_id`, `etapeables`.`etapeable_id` as `pivot_etapeable_id`, `etapeables`.`date` as `pivot_date` FROM `entreprises` inner join `etapeables` on `entreprises`.`id` = `etapeables`.`etapeable_id` WHERE `entreprises`.`deleted_at` IS NULL and `etapeables`.`etape_id` in ('12', '13', '14') and `etapeables`.`etapeable_type` = 'Entreprise'
```

As you can see the second request begins with:

```
SELECT `entreprises`.`id`, `entreprises`.*
```

So the select method is not taken into account. Is this a Laravel bug or is there an other solution for this issue?

Comment: What select method is not getting taken into account?

Comment: I think the request still selects entreprises.* , even if it was said to overwrite the select with 'entrerprises.id'

Comment: I think this might just be an issue with your version off laravel. Try to run composer update

Comment: I have reported that issue here : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3913

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported by Laravel (neither 4.* nor 5.*).

Take a look [at the issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3913) created by [@edi9999](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993501):  where Taylor Otwell states:

> This is a known issue. We don't allow "selects" on by-many relationships.

There is [another issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2966) (created at the end of 2013) where Taylor says

> We don't currently support limiting the selects on those relations because if it's not done properly it can break the query. You can remove the columns once the data has been retrieved if you like.